# Is possible receive UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification after has received UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification?

Tags: ios

When APP go to background,is possible receive UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification?

My APP have some trouble,because sometimes first receive UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification,and then receive UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification,its unbelievably.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check [The Background Transition Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html)
 for more info.